# Java DSL Equivalent of Spring Integration Kafka Endpoint Configured in XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

I have the following XML configuration for a Kafka outbound channel adapter:

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    channel="activityOutputChannel">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>

</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
<task:executor id="taskExecutor"
               pool-size="5-25"
               queue-capacity="20"
               keep-alive="120"/>
```

This works just fine. I am trying to replicate this in the Java DSL, but I can't get too far. So far, I just have this:

```
.handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaConfig)
        .addProducer(producerMetadata, brokerAddress)
        .get());
```

I can't figure out how to add the `taskExecutor` and the `poller` with the DSL.

Any insight on how to incorporate these into my overall `IntegrationFlow` is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Integration components (e.g. `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>`) consist with two beans: `AbstractEndpoint` to accept messages from the `input-channel` and `MessageHandler` to handle message.

So, `Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter()` is about `MessageHandler`. Any other endpoint-specific properties are up to the second `Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<H>> endpointConfigurer` argument of `.handle()` EIP-method:

```
.handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaConfig)
    .addProducer(producerMetadata, brokerAddress),
           e -> e.id("kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter")
                 .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                        .receiveTimeout(0)
                                        .taskExecutor(this.taskExecutor)));
```

See [Reference Manual](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) for more information.